# Explanation for program

Tags: c

Its my exams next week and we were given a bank of questions out of which we need to provide valid solutions with explanations of the given code. I am not able to understand this code. Attaching the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {     
      int a = 800, b = 100, c;     
        if(!a >= 400)         
       b = 500;     
         c = 900;      
       printf("b = %d c = %d\n", b, c);      
        return 0; 
    }
```

The answer after execution of this problem is b=100 and c=900. But i have not understood how.

Comment: "Explanation for program" is not a useful title.

Comment: Figure out what !a means.

Comment: My previous comment was too cryptic, sorry. I assume you're learning C. Fire up a debugger and single step through the program. Then look to see how !a affects the execution.

Comment: I will advise to indent properly the code, after it becomes clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with what everyone else mentions:

1. Indentation & curly brackets would help make this easier on you.
2. As written, the if statement only applies to this line "b=500;"
3. !a is the opposite of a.
   a >= 400 is true
   !a >= 400 is false, thus "b = 500" is not executed.
4. Result b is still 100 and c is assigned 900

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!a >= 400)
```

Since logical not `!` has higher precedence, this is equivalent to `(!a) >= 400`. The left side evaluates to `0` (because a is non-zero, so `!a` is `0`) making the entire expression is false. Also note the code indentation isn't significant to the compiler.

Comment: This is correct because !a == 0. Really. !a >= 400 is not equal to a < 400.